# Convert old advise ad-set-arg to new advice

Tags: advice, nadvice

How would I convert the following old style advice to a new style advice?

```lisp
(setq python--pdb-breakpoint-string "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()")

(defadvice compile (before ad-compile-smart activate)
  "Advises `compile' so it sets the argument COMINT to t
if breakpoints are present in `python-mode' files"
  (when (derived-mode-p major-mode 'python-mode)
    (save-excursion
      (save-match-data
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (if (re-search-forward (concat "^\\s-*" python--pdb-breakpoint-string "$")
                               (point-max) t)
            ;; set COMINT argument to `t'.
            (ad-set-arg 1 t))))))
```

Snippet from: https://masteringemacs.org/article/compiling-running-scripts-emacs

---

From [Porting old advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-old-advice.html#Porting-old-advice), the recommendations are [`:around` or `:filter-args`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/compile.el#L1560).

Using `:filter-args`, I'm at a loss for what to return for the first argument of [`compile`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/compile.el#L1560).  The first argument is `command`.  I have no clue what that is, or might be, and don't know how to find it during advising/let it pass through.

```lisp
(advice-add 'compile :filter-args
            (lambda ()
              (when (derived-mode-p major-mode 'python-mode)
                (save-excursion
                  (save-match-data
                    (goto-char (point-min))
                    (if (re-search-forward (concat "^\\s-*" python--pdb-breakpoint-string "$") (point-max) t)
                        ;; new arglist: 
                        ;; (command t)
                        ))))))
```

Using `:around`, I think I have the same issue, but it's hard to tell.  I'm getting overwhelmed by the documentation.  It seems like I would need to call `apply` if the `if` passes and call the original `compile` otherwise:

```lisp
(advice-add 'compile :around
            (lambda (oldcompile)
              (when (derived-mode-p major-mode 'python-mode)
                (save-excursion
                  (save-match-data
                    (goto-char (point-min))
                    (if (re-search-forward (concat "^\\s-*" my-python-break-string "$")
                                           (point-max) t)
                        (apply oldcompile command t)
                       oldcompile))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the documentation for `add-function` or the corresponding page in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advice-combinators.html):

If you define an `:filter-args` advice your function `FUNCTION` advising `OLDFUN` is called as follows:

> `(lambda (&rest r) (apply OLDFUN (funcall FUNCTION r)))`

That means you get the arguments as list, may modify that list, and pass it as list of arguments to the old function.

```el
(setq python--pdb-breakpoint-string "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()")

(defun my-compile-advice (args)
  "Advises `compile' so it sets the argument COMINT to t
if breakpoints are present in `python-mode' files"
  (when (derived-mode-p major-mode 'python-mode)
    (save-excursion
      (save-match-data
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (if (re-search-forward (concat "^\\s-*" python--pdb-breakpoint-string "$")
                               (point-max) t)
            ;; set COMINT argument to `t'.
            (let ((command (car args)))
              (setq args (list command t)))))))
  args)

(advice-add 'compile :filter-args #'my-compile-advice)
```

I recommend always to define a function for advising OLDFUN. That gives you the possibility to jump to the definition of the advice from the help of OLDFUN.
Furthermore, it simplifies debugging a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know how your function will be invoked, that is, what arguments it will take and what result must return, [(info "(elisp) Advice combinators")](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advice-combinators.html) or `C-h add-function` says:

> :filter-args `(lambda (&rest r) (apply OLDFUN (funcall FUNCTION r)))`

thus your function (that is `FUNCTION` in above) should take exactly one argument, which is always a list (suggested by `&rest`), and return another list (suggested by `apply`).

For example, we want to swap `A` and `B` in `foo`

```
(defun foo (a b) (list a b))

(define-advice foo (:filter-args (args) swap)
  "Swap A and B."
  (list (nth 1 args) (nth 0 args)))

(foo 1 2)
;; => (2 1)
```

`:around` is the most generic one, it can replace all others

> :around `(lambda (&rest r) (apply FUNCTION OLDFUN r))`

so your function should accept one or more argument, the first is `OLDFUN`, thus both of the following work

```
(define-advice foo (:around (old-fun a b) swap-2)
  (funcall old-fun b a))

(define-advice foo (:around (old-fun &rest r) swap-3)
  (apply old-fun (nreverse r)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the closest replacement for

```
(defadvice FOO (before ...)
  ... (ad-set-arg N V) ...)
```

is

```
(advice-add FOO :around
  (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
    ... (setf (nth N args) V) ...
    (apply orig-fun args)))
```

But as Tobias points out, this can fail if there is no Nth argument.  Also using `setf/setq` makes you lose valuable karma points.  So you're better off writing code that's not as similar-looking as the original.  E.g.

```
(advice-add 'compile :around
  (lambda (orig-fun command &optional comint)
    (funcall orig-fun command
             ;; Set COMINT argument to t if there's a Python breakpoint.
             (or (when (derived-mode-p major-mode 'python-mode)
                   (save-excursion
                     (save-match-data
                       (goto-char (point-min))
                       (re-search-forward
                        (concat "^\\s-*" python--pdb-breakpoint-string "$")
                        nil t))))
                 comint))))
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, I also had `(setf (nth N args) V)` in my code before. But, you need to be careful with that. It might be that the argument N is optional. If the user does not specify it `(setf (nth N args) V)` fails. In fact, the `COMINT` argument of `compile` is optional.

Comment: @Tobias: you're right that reality is more complex than my example suggests.  I'll clarify.